# JSON encode comma delimited row

Tags: json

I'm trying to add an autocomplete tokenizer script to some form fields and one issue I'm having is if a person saves multiple values for the field the autocomplete suggestions come back with all of his values as one long value instead of them being single values delimited by the comma. I first tried to simply explode the value but it doesn't format it correctly in the JSON encode.

Here is my PHP file:

```
//connection information
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "myuser";
 $password = "mypass";
 $database = "mydb";
 $param = ($_GET["term"]);
 
 //make connection
 $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
 $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
 
 //query the database
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT cb_activities FROM jos_comprofiler WHERE cb_activities REGEXP '^$param'");
 
 //build array of results
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  $activities[$x] = array(cb_activitiesterm => $row[cb_activities]); 
  }
 
 //echo JSON to page
 $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($activities) . ")";
 echo $response;
 
 mysql_close($server);
```

This gives the output like this:

```
[{"cb_activities":"Kicking Cats,"},{"cb_activities":"baseball,hockey,"}]
but I need it to output like this:
[{"cb_activities":"Kicking Cats,"},{"cb_activities":"baseball,"},"cb_activities":"hockey,"}]
```

I also need to find a way to prevent duplicate entries from populating. For instance, the way it is now, say 10 people all have kicking cats selected as a value, it will display 10 times in the autocomplete suggestions.

How do I set this up to correctly delimit at the commas and then weed out duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

NM the duplicate issue, I just added select distinct instead of just select, this json thing has me overcomplicating things now lol. Now if I can just figure out how to delimit properly at the comma all will be good.